# Insert blank record on page load if record does not exist for current user

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership, sql-server-ce, user-profile

I'm working on using the membership functionality of the ASP .Net sites.  There are multiple ways to create users and one way is to create users and add a user profile to the system.  The other is to use an enhanced wizard then add the user and then their profile information.  Well, if you go route 1, then the user does not get a record inserted into the user profile table and then when the user goes to update their profile, then on the page load I would like the page to look for their record.  If one does not exist, insert a blank one.  Does anyone have a sample script to look up a user's profile based on their unique id in SQL CE?  If the record does not exist (record count = 0) then insert a new blank record.

Comment: This should be handled for you as long as you use the built in libraries... I've never had to explicitly create a user's profile record.

Comment: Thanks Jason P.  I believe this fixed it.